# Trouble including array output in another array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have the following code:

```
$tags = get_tags(array('exclude' => 46,5,101,22,122,7,102,15,104,47,105,66,43,123, 'fields' => ids));
$tagString = implode (',' , $tags);
echo $tagString;
```

Which echos out as...
10,121,20,36,23,66,24,21,105,76,82,17,22,122,43,47,102,5,6,106,8,75,54,38,57,86,56,101,123,95,25,62,16,39,40,69,37,9,42,7,15,41,87,73,85,104

This is great. However, I actually want to include the result (which I guess is $tagString) in another array as follows...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tag__in' => array (46, 5, 101, 22, 122, 7, 102, 15, 104, 47, 105, 66, 43, 123),
    'tag__not_in' => array ($tagString)
);
```

I've tried removing brackets adding single / double / no quotes, removing the word 'array' in front of $tagString across all combinations but it just doesn't work. When I manually create...

```
'tag__not_in' => array (10,121,20,36,23,24,21,76,82,17,6,106,8,75,54,38,57,86,56,95,25,62,16,39,40,69,37,9,42,41,87,73,85)
```

The code works perfectly. How can I get the output from $tagString to be the content of 'tag__not_in' array within the brackets? Is this possible?

========

Update to reflect Amal's code...

```
$tags = get_tags(array('exclude' => 46,5,101,22,122,7,102,15,104,47,105,66,43,123, 'fields' => ids));
$tagString = implode (',' , $tags);
echo $tagString;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tag__in' => array (46, 5, 101, 22, 122, 7, 102, 15, 104, 47, 105, 66, 43, 123),
    /*'tag__not_in' => array (10,121,20,36,23,24,21,76,82,17,6,106,8,75,54,38,57,86,56,95,25,62,16,39,40,69,37,9,42,41,87,73,85)*/
    'tag__not_in' => explode(',', $tagString)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

`$tagString` is a string - simply inserting it in `array(...)` won't create an array (unless you use `eval()`, which is generally a bad idea).  Simply use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to create an array from the comma-separated string, like so:

```
'tag__not_in' => explode(',', $tagString)
```

Comment: Hi Amal, thank you my friend. I have tried it (and included the full code block in my question) but it outputs up to the `echo $tagString;` and then nothing. I've tried as before adding brackets and inserting `array` before explode and surrounding it with brackets but it either results in the code being ignored completely or returning nothing. Can you see anything else there? Many thanks.

Comment: I think I've found the problem @Amal - I've added print_r and it is returning the following... 

`Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 121 [2] => 20 [3] => 36 [4] => 23 [5] => 66 [6] => 24 [7] => 21 [8] => 105 [9] => 76 [10] => 82 [11] => 17 [12] => 22 [13] => 122 [14] => 43 ... )` 

I need it to return a comma separated list such as... 

`Array (10,121,20,36,23,66,24,21,105,76,82,17,22,122,43 ... )` 

i.e. lose the...

`[x] =>` and include a comma instead?