# convert array output to string in PHP and then add to another array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm not certain I'm asking the right question but here goes...

```
$tags = get_tags(array('exclude' => 46,5,101,22,122,7,102,15,104,47,105,66,43,123, 'fields' => ids));
$tagString = implode (',' , $tags);
echo $tagString;
```

When I echo this out via the last line it gives me a lovely list of comma separated numbers (the right numbers too fortunately). However, I don't want to echo them I want to include them in more code as follows...

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post', 
'tag__in' => array (46, 5, 101, 22, 122, 7, 102, 15, 104, 47, 105, 66, 43, 123),
'tag__not_in' => array (comma separated list output by echo $tagString in same format as 'tag__in')
);
```

It has been suggested using explode but when I do that it returns...

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 121 [2] => 20 [3] => 36 etc etc)
```

I need to lose all the formatting and just get the comma separated list.

Possibly I'm approaching this wrong and maybe I'm not making sense but hopefully someone can  follow what I'm trying to achieve. Any help appreciated.

It is linked to this question which got me this far... [Trouble including array output in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169166/trouble-including-array-output-in-another-array)

Update:

Thank you James who put me on the right lines. This is the code that did the trick...

```
$includeTags = array(46,5,101,22,122,7,102,15,104,47,105,66,43,123);
$excludeTags = get_tags(array('exclude' => $includeTags, 'fields' => ids));

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tag__in' => $includeTags,
    'tag__not_in' => $excludeTags
);
```

I've changed the array names for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm definitely not sure what you are asking.  First, I'm surprised your original array works at all.  You are using a mix between an associative array and just an incremental array it looks like.

Can you try something like:

```
$excludeArr = array(46,5,101,22,122,7,102,15,104,47,105,66,43,123);
$tags = get_tags(array('exclude' => $excludeArr, 'fields' => ids));
$tagString = implode (',' , $tags);
echo $tagString;
```

Where the `exclude` is an array itself. Then:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post', 
'tag__in' => $excludeArr,
'tag__not_in' => $excludeArr
);
```

None of that `$args` array makes much since since the `in` and `not_in` appear to be the same, though.

If you just need `$excludeArr`as a string, you can `implode(",", $excludeArr);`

**EDIT**

After seeing your update, I'm editing my answer as requested to show the 2 seperate arrays.

```
$includeTags = array(46,5,101,22,122,7,102,15,104,47,105,66,43,123);
$excludeTags = get_tags(array('exclude' => $includeTags, 'fields' => ids));

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tag__in' => $includeTags,
    'tag__not_in' => $excludeTags
);
```

Comment: Just re `in` and `not_in` - they are basically opposites. `in` is all the ids I list manually as they are fixed. `not_in` will change as new tags / ids are added. I'm therefore trying to calculate it by using the `get_tags` function which has the ability to `get_tags` except the tag ids I list to be excluded (is a Wordpress function). Therefore `in` includes the tag ids I list and `not_in` is basically all the tags except `$tags` \ `$tagString`

Comment: James, just to let you know your code basically put me on the right lines and I have it working exactly as I need. On that basis, I will add my code to the question and if you would like to edit your answer I can tick it. I know my question was confusing.

Comment: @PaulBrown I see your update, but where does your question stand now?  Can you add what is still not working for you?  Is it that you need both the exclude and include arrays to be strings?

Comment: Hi @James no - I felt that my code was really just a reworked version of the code you provided but my question confused you a little. There is nothing outstanding - the code I added to the bottom of my question works perfectly but I didn't want to add it as an answer as I felt it was close to plagiarizing you. On that basis would you like to either edit your answer or add a new one so that I can tick it?

Answer (score 1):

for block 2 cant you just use

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post', 
'tag__in' => $tagString,
);
```

Comment: There should be no ending comma after `$tagString` in this example.  Tried to edit but I guess it didn't go through.

Comment: @James its perfectly valid to have a comma, not required, but valid and preferred by some of us (is codding not grammar  :-))

Comment: I guess you are right.  I just tested it.  Could have swore it threw an error on me when I had done that previously saying it was expecting key/values after the comma.  Ah well.

Comment: Thank you but no because block 2 basically says include posts that are tagged with any of (`tag__in` ids) but if they are also tagged with any of (`tag__not_in` ids) then they should be excluded. `$tagString` is basically calculating all the tag ids that aren't included in `tag__in` so it returns all ids except 46,5,101, etc

Answer (score 0):

Your best friend is named

```
serialize()
```

(http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.serialize.php)

This simply converts the whole array contents to a string. :)

Comment: Thank you - is 1am here in UK but will look at that in more detail tomorrow. Appreciate the signpost.

Answer (score 0):

```
$includeTags = array(46,5,101,22,122,7,102,15,104,47,105,66,43,123);
$excludeTags = get_tags(array('exclude' => $includeTags, 'fields' => ids));

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post', 
'posts_per_page' => 12,
'paged' => $paged,
'tag__in' => $includeTags,
'tag__not_in' => $excludeTags
);
```